# Is $9.\overline{9} = 10$?

Tags: fractions

If you divide $10$ by $3$, you get $3.\overline{3}$ but $3.\overline{3}\times{3}=9.\overline{9}$ Does this make $9.\overline{9}=10$?

Comment: Yes, see the answer to the question why $0.999\cdots =1$ holds.

Comment: The formula for the geometric series easily gives you the answer.

Comment: Not in the $3$-adic metric.  Try to prove convergence of $(9/1)+(9/10)+(9/100)+...$ to $10$ in that metric.  You can't, because all the $3$-adic terms are multiples of $100_3=9$!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sure does!

One way to convince yourself is to look for a number in decimal representation that's greater than $9.\bar{9}$ but less than $10$.

Comment: does that mean that $x.\overline{9}=y$ when y = the integer above x?

Comment: That's correct.